# Can I place a modifier after a colon?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, modifiers, colons

Can I place a modifier after a colon?

For example:

> She opened the door, planning to go outside.

vs

> She opened the door: planning to go outside.

Comment: I think why would you want to, what are you writing, and what do you hope to achieve, are the things we need to know. Otherwise, it's not a meaningful question.

Comment: I read a colon as an arrow that trumpets the following: a big announcement. "Planning to go outside" is too prosaic.

Comment: As Yosef says ... and indeed, does one 'plan' (I'd say the default sense is 'formulate plans' here) so prosaic an act? 'Intending'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a literary piece, you can do anything you want, as long as you are understood. It is indeed not idiomatic to separate the verb phrase from its modifier by a colon.

However, your second sentence can carry different connotations. Colon marks a pause, a sharp pause, making the reader stop and wait for the next information with increased attention. So it adds to the suspense of your sentence. Each reader will understand maybe different things. I for example understand that

> She opened the door:

is an important, central information. And why did she open the door?

> *[because she was]* planning to go outside.

As [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/punctuation) explains:

> We commonly use a colon between sentences ***when the second sentence explains or justifies the first sentence***:
>
> - Try to keep your flat clean and tidy: it will sell more easily.

The difference is that in your example you are separating the main part of the sentence (which could be an independent statement) from the non-finite clause that explains it.

If this sentence is in a suspenseful context where every thought and move counts, then it can be a successful usage of colon. However, in a more relaxed context, this colon may seem out of place. You need to assess if this sharp pause will help draw attention to something important or if it will rather unnecessarily interrupt the flow of what you are describing.

Comment: It's an unusual place to situate a sizeable dramatic pause. Surely that would occur before the door-opening: _She deliberated about going outside ... she opened the door._ (Are there Balrogs or paparazzi out there?)